# Riot js undefined value

Tags: riot.js

Someone can tell me why my code doesn't work please ??

I get "this.username is undefined" and i don't really understand why...

Here the code :

```
riot.tag2('test', '<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" oninput={validate} value="" /> <h4>{username_valid}</h4>', '', '', function(opts) {
    this.validate = function(e) {
        this.username_valid = (this.username.value.length > 3) ? 'Valid' : 'Invalid'
    };
});
```

Thanks for your help..

Comment: Which Riot version are you using? If you are using v3, you need to use refs to reference the variables. So in the input, you should have ref="username" and in the method this.refs.username.value  . http://riotjs.com/guide/#named-elements

Answer (score 3):

Just because it's so hard to read, I hope you're not actually writing the component using the riot API. I transcribed it into a tag so we can have a better look:

```
<test>

  <input
    type="text"
    name="username"
    placeholder="username"
    oninput={validate}
    value=""/>

  <h4>{username_valid}</h4>

  <script>

    this.validate = function(e) {
        this.username_valid = (this.username.value.length > 3) ? 'Valid' : 'Invalid'
    }

  </script>
</test>
```

You're trying to get username from the input element. `this` in a tag refers to the scope of the script, not the DOM elements. There are a few ways you can get the input value

1. Add `ref='username'` to the `<input>` tag.
   Then use `this.refs.username.value` to get the value from a ref
2. In the `validate` function, use `e.target.value` to get the element from the oninput event
3. Use `this.root.querySelectorAll('input')[0].value` for a scoped DOM query